# Calculating sandwich estimator

Tags: multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error, sandwich, qr-decomposition

Considering design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$  $(n>p)$ and response $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The sandwich estimator can be calculated directly using 
$$(X^TX)^{-1}X^T diag(r^2) X (X^TX)^{-1}$$
where $r$ is the residuals. The sandwich estimator 
then is the the diagonal of the result. 
To avoid calculating the inverse, 
we can also get the sandwich estimator by first 
projecting $diag(r)$ onto the column space of $X$ 
and then take the diagonal of the product of 
the transpose of the coefficients and 
the coefficients (Note that the coefficients is a ${p\times n}$ matrix).

Since we have already had the QR decomposition when
solving the linear system, i.e.
$$Q^T X \beta = \begin{pmatrix} R \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$Q^T y = \begin{pmatrix} \tilde{y_1} \\ \tilde{y_2} \end{pmatrix}$$
where $R$ is a $p\times p$ upper triangular matrix, then
we can reuse $R$ and get $Q^T diag(r)$ and back substitute to get the coefficients.

Observe that the residual is actually
$$r = Q \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \tilde{y_2} \end{pmatrix}.$$
Can we write 
$Q^T diag\left(Q \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \tilde{y_2} \end{pmatrix}\right)$
as some form so that we only need minimal number of operations on $\tilde{y_2}$ to get $Q^T diag(r)$?
In general, is there any other procedure
to utilize the QR decomposition efficiently
to get the sandwich estimator?

Edit: $\tilde{y_1}$ is the first $d$ elements
and $\tilde{y_2}$ is the last $(n-d)$ elements of $Q^T y$.

Comment: Are you using the twiddle notation to represent the fitted values? What is $\tilde{y}_2$?

Comment: @AdamO No. $\tilde{y_2}$ is last $(n-d)$ elements of $Q^T y$.